# Concurrent hash map Java's internal mechanism

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, concurrenthashmap

As we all know concurrent hash map allows multiple threads to read/write simultaneously using segment locks.
My question is:
How Java internally manages the map when a thread t1 is writing on a bucket and thread t2 is reading on the same bucket and vice versa ?
Does Java makes copy of the map before any thread starts writing on a map and merger them after write operation or what is actual way Java adopts ?

Waiting for a correct answer.

Comment: Some basic Googling is in order: http://javahungry.blogspot.com/2015/02/how-concurrenthashmap-works-in-java-internal-implementation.html

Comment: Better yet, such question can be answered just by reading the source code.

Comment: I have went though it and it just mentioning what is possible and what not. It didnt described how java handling it man. Answer it if you know the answer. why you marked as inappropriate. If you dont know the asnwer you can skip it.

Comment: *"Waiting for a correct answer."* -  I was going to answer, but then I saw this.  My answer might be incorrect ... so I had better not tell you what it is.  :-)

Comment: *"It didnt described how java handling it man."* - That is RUBBISH.  The source code (the Java, not the comments) is whats gets executed.  It specifies exactly what happens.  If you can't get what you want from the comments, read the code.   Don't ask someone else to do it for you.

Comment: Please you can share you answer. I hope it will solve my problem

Comment: Short answer.  No.  You can solve your problem yourself.  See above.

Comment: @Stephen, i wrote about the first comment of http://javahungry.blogspot.com/2015/02/how-concurrenthashmap-works-in-java-internal-implementation.html.  i am not talking about source code. calm down man,

Comment: I'm calm now.  But my answer is still the same.  Read the source code.

Comment: Re, "...How Java internally manages the map...",    `ConcurrentHashMap` is part of the Java Runtime Environment, of which there is more than one implementation.  There's no requirement for any given JDK (e.g., IBM's proprietary version) to implement `ConcurrentHashMap` in the same way that Oracle's JDK implements it.  It only has to behave in the same way that Oracle's implementation behaves.

Comment: Your question has a wrong premise as there is no special action that a reader has to perform, it will simply read the value which will happen to be either, the old value or the new value, depending on the timing. But what is your actual problem that answering this question ought to solve?

Answer (score 1):

No, Java doesn't make a copy of the map nor the segment, and doesn't "merge" a copy into the map after write operation. 
`put` and `get` methods put a lock on the segment, so two threads don't have access to the same segment at the same time have.
Please take a look at the implementation of `put` and `get`:
http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.java#ConcurrentHashMap.put%28java.lang.Object%2Cjava.lang.Object%29

```
907     public V put(K key, V value) {
908         if (value == null)
909             throw new NullPointerException();
910         int hash = hash(key.hashCode());
911         return segmentFor(hash).put(key, hash, value, false);
912     }

795     public V  get(Object key) {
796         int hash = hash(key.hashCode());
797         return segmentFor(hash).get(key, hash);
798     }
```

Both methods calculate a hash of a key, then call `segmentFor(hash)` that returns a segment for a given hash, and then call `put` and `get` methods on this segment.

---

A declaration of the segment is here, it's a descendant of ReentrantLock:
http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.java#ConcurrentHashMap.Segment

```
 static final class Segment<K,V> extends ReentrantLock implements Serializable {
```

and an implementation of `get` ang `put` within the segment:

```
351         V  readValueUnderLock(HashEntry<K,V> e) {
352             lock();
353             try {
354                 return e.value;
355             } finally {
356                 unlock();
357             }
358         }
359 
360         /* Specialized implementations of map methods */
361 
362         V  get(Object key, int hash) {
363             if (count != 0) { // read-volatile
364                 HashEntry<K,V> e = getFirst(hash);
365                 while (e != null) {
366                     if (e.hash == hash && key.equals(e.key)) {
367                         V v = e.value;
368                         if (v != null)
369                             return v;
370                         return readValueUnderLock(e); // recheck
371                     }
372                     e = e.next;
373                 }
374             }
375             return null;
376         }
```

---

```
444         V put(K key, int hash, V value, boolean onlyIfAbsent) {
445             lock();
446             try {
447                 int c = count;
448                 if (c++ > threshold) // ensure capacity
449                     rehash();
450                 HashEntry<K,V>[] tab = table;
451                 int index = hash & (tab.length - 1);
452                 HashEntry<K,V> first = tab[index];
453                 HashEntry<K,V> e = first;
454                 while (e != null && (e.hash != hash || !key.equals(e.key)))
455                     e = e.next;
456 
457                 V oldValue;
458                 if (e != null) {
459                     oldValue = e.value;
460                     if (!onlyIfAbsent)
461                         e.value = value;
462                 }
463                 else {
464                     oldValue = null;
465                     ++modCount;
466                     tab[index] = new HashEntry<K,V>(key, hash, first, value);
467                     count = c; // write-volatile
468                 }
469                 return oldValue;
470             } finally {
471                 unlock();
472             }
473         }
```

These methods simply call `lock()` and `unlock()` to prevent/allow other threads from/for accessing the segment while they are doing their job.